# What is $V$ in $a$=$V$$dv$/$dx$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, velocity, calculus

$a$=instantaneous acceleration

$V$=instantaneous velocity

$x$=position

$dx$=small Chang in position

$a$=$dv$/$dt$

multiplying numerator and denominator by $dx$,we get

$a$=$dv$.$dx$/$dx$.$dt$

now we know $V$=$dx$/$dt$,

so,$a$ becomes $V$$dv$/$dx$

What is $V$ in $a$=$V$$dv$/$dx$??is it initial velocity?Or is it the velocity of the moment when we are finding the acceleration???is it velocity as a function of position or time???

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/763457/2451

Comment: Hi Aakash. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Answer (score 0):

Purely algebraically we see that
$$\frac {\Delta v}{\Delta t}=\frac {\Delta v}{\Delta x}\times \frac {\Delta x}{\Delta t}.$$
It can be shown that in the limit as $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$ this becomes
$$\frac {dv}{dt}=\frac {dv}{dx}\times \frac{dx}{dt}=\frac {dv}{dx}\times v.$$
$v$ is the instantaneous velocity.

Comment: Instantaneous velocity of which instant?

Comment: At the instant at which we are finding the instantaneous acceleration.